# Accessing A Search bar created in App.xaml, in App.xaml.cs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Don't like the height of the Navigation Bar / Header bar on Android, so built a custom one, in a ControlTemplate, in App.xaml .
It also includes a search bar, when I try and access this search bar (named "x:Name="HeaderSearch"), from App.xaml.cs it doesnt work.
Code below;

App.xaml

```
< x:Class="AltusApp.App">
<Application.Resources>

<!-- Application resource dictionary -->
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HomePageTemplate">

        <!--Begin Header-->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
                 <RowDefinition Height="92*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#bababa">
                <Image Source="altuslogo.jpg" WidthRequest="23" HeightRequest="23" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,5,5,0"/>

                <Image Source="home.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="5,5,0,5">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnHomeButtonPressed"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>

                <Image Source="back.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="35,5,0,0">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnBackButtonPressed"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>

                <SearchBar x:Name="HeaderSearch" SearchButtonPressed="searchenter" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="40,5,25,5"/>

                <ListView x:Name="NavListView" />


            </Grid>
        <!-- End Header -->

        <!-- Begin Content -->
            <ContentPresenter VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
         <!-- End Content -->
        </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

`

for App.xaml.cs i've tried

```
public void HeaderSearch_searchenter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { String Keyword = AltusApp.App.HeaderSearch.text; }
public void HeaderSearch_searchenter(object sender, EventArgs e)         
    {String Keyword = HeaderSearch.text; }
```

I get 'App' does not contain a definition for 'HeaderSearch'

or

The name 'HeaderSearch' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what you want to access is a view within a control template, and that is just a resource. So basically, the `HeaderSearch` does not actually "exist". Once you use the template somewhere, only then it will actually come to being. If you want some logic replicated in multiple places, a custom control would probably be a better fit.

When the template is then actually used, you could access the `HeaderSearch` by going through the visual tree and searching for the control with this name inside. You can find some example methods for this purpose [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18599/visual-tree-helper).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will look into that but at a quick glance it looks beyond me.  Is there no way interact with the object once it's becomes an instance ?

Comment: Basically, resources are almost like "blueprints". From what I see you goal is rather to have a "master page" that will have the header, and then contain the content inside. I think you should look into `NavigationPage` and customize that itself. A generic `ControlTemplate` is not what you are after

Comment: The best solution would probably be to build a custom header as a custom control and then use it in the main `NavigationPage` instead of the built in one